Battery connected inbetween plates of capacitor
I came across a nice conceptual question on how will things change like potential,  capacitance and stored energy if a capacitor is charged by a battery connected in between plates of a capacitor?
Can you relate the changes when  battery connected across and in between capacitor lead?

I don't think this would be much different than connecting two open-ended wires to the ends of a battery. After all, the capacitor's plates are just conductors like a wire.

The potential difference (voltage) between the plates would be the same, but the physical presence of the battery in the space between the plates would alter the electrical permittivity of the space, and thus alter the value of the capacitance.
Hope this helps.
